# what is the meaning of Input y contains NaN

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
# Fit each pipeline on the training data
for pipeline in pipelines:
    pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-39301fb0712f> in <cell line: 19>()
     18 # Fit each pipeline on the training data
     19 for pipeline in pipelines:
---> 20     pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype, estimator_name, input_name)
    159                 "#estimators-that-handle-nan-values"
    160             )
--> 161         raise ValueError(msg_err)
    162 
    163 

ValueError: Input y contains NaN.
```

i want to identify and modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fit your data, you have to clean the data from NaNs. You can do this for example with [numpy.isnan](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html#numpy.isnan) function, by creating a boolean mask from the NaNs and inverting it with the tilde (`~`):

```
import numpy as np


x_train = np.array([1,2,np.nan,4, 5])
y_train = np.array([np.nan, 7, 8, 9, 10])

nanmask = np.isnan(x_train) | np.isnan(y_train)

x_train_cleaned = x_train[~nanmask]
y_train_cleaned = y_train[~nanmask]
```

In this case, the input arrays `x_train` and `y_train` contained NaNs, but the cleaned data does not:

```py
>>> x_train_cleaned
array([2., 4., 5.])
>>> y_train_cleaned
array([ 7.,  9., 10.])
```

After cleaning the data, use it for fitting:

```py
pipeline.fit(x_train_cleaned, y_train_cleaned)
```